# GitHub Conflict Resolution issue

Tags: salesforcedx, github

I've been working for several days in SFDX on the "Proof-Org" branch from my git master-repo. Now I've done a pull request on the branch, but there's a file with 951 conflicts! The file is **sourcePathInfos.json**, and a typical conflict looks like this:

```
    [
        "/Users/pmcclellan/Documents/GitHub/protontext-repo/force-app/main/default/aura/EmojiPicker/EmojiPickerController.js",
        {
<<<<<<< Proof-Org
            "sourcePath": "/Users/pmcclellan/Documents/GitHub/protontext-repo/force-app/main/default/aura/EmojiPicker/EmojiPickerController.js",
            "isDirectory": false,
=======
            "state": "n",
            "sourcePath": "/Users/pmcclellan/Documents/GitHub/protontext-repo/force-app/main/default/aura/EmojiPicker/EmojiPickerController.js",
            "isDirectory": false,
            "isMetadataFile": false,
>>>>>>> master
            "size": 744,
            "modifiedTime": 1520036474829,
            "changeTime": 1520036474829,
            "contentHash": "859e695c36b1d1ef8d03d7a890b108b0c6c9f3d1",
<<<<<<< Proof-Org
            "isMetadataFile": false,
            "state": "u",
=======
>>>>>>> master
            "isWorkspace": false,
            "isArtifactRoot": false
        }
    ],
```

A lot of the conflicts seem to be simply the difference between `"state":"u"` and `"state":"n"`. What are state u and state n?

This isn't a file that I've done any editing on, so I'm in the dark about what it does or how to resolve the conflicts. The filepath for it (displayed in the github conflict resolution page) is `.sfdx/orgs/test-ydnidvfaiadq@example.com/sourcePathInfos.json`, which includes a username like those created for scratch orgs -- though this is an old one, not current.

Looking for advice on:

1. What is this file?
2. Did I screw something up that created the conflicts?
3. Will I screw up something big if I accept all the Proof-Org changes?
4. Can I just exclude this file from the pull request without messing something up?
5. Is there a way to bulk accept the changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. What is this file?

Internal housekeeping files that should not concern you (and that you should never intentionally modify).

> 2. Did I screw something up that created the conflicts?

You committed the `.sfdx` directory. This directory is intentionally hidden, because it's not meant to be included in the repo. Unless you know what a specific "dot file" (a file or directory starting with ".") is, you should never, ever commit them to the repo. This includes `.project`, `.sfdx`, `.temp`, `.metadata`, or any other dot files you may come across. They're not meant to be portable. The sole exception are files that you *know* what they do, specifically `.gitignore` and `.forceignore`.

> 3. Will I screw up something big if I accept all the Proof-Org changes?

Never update housekeeping files. The results may be unpredictable.

> 4. Can I just exclude this file from the pull request without messing something up?

Things are likely already beyond any casual salvaging. You'll need to do a `git rm .sfdx`, commit the merge, and push it back up to the server, where hopefully it won't mess up anyone else. Then, add `.sfdx` to `.gitignore` to make sure that doesn't happen again. Afterwards, you'll need to `sfdx force:source:pull` to get things back in working order, and, depending on if you've logged in to just the project, `sfdx force:auth:web:login` as well. You might even need to create a new scratch org if you lose your authentication token in the process. Consider setting a password and username you can log back in to afterwards to avoid losing work.

> 5. Is there a way to bulk accept the changes?

Yes, but don't do it (see the Git documentation on how you'd accept incoming changes automatically).

Comment: thanks. SFDX and GitHub are new to me, so I'm just figuring out basics. My initial push to the github repo was following step-by-step instructions from a Salesforce blog. I'll have to figure out where I went wrong...

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe you can trash `sourcePathInfos.json` and start again. It's one of the files that tracks what has/n't been changed when doing `force:source:pull/push`. So if you delete it and then do a push/pull on the scratch org, it will push/pull *everything* once and then regenerate the file.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, this file (and everything under `.sfdx`) should not be under source control, as it's a bookkeeping artifact used by SFDX rather than a component of your application. In this case, it's keeping track of the source state vis-a-vis your local store and scratch orgs.

I would recommend simply removing it from the repository, and adding `.sfdx` to your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help @sfdcfox. I need to make sure I understand your instructions. To be clear, there are no other users and no other branches, so it's probably not as bad as it could have been.

Seems like I needed a .gitignore file (like the .forceignore file) in my SFDX project prior to initial push to my GitHub repo. I'm assuming that would be positioned at the top level of my local repo, right beside .sfdx, .vim-force.com, .vscode, etc., and would include those directories.

So my gitHub repo would only include config, data, and force-app directories and the README.md.

My next steps include:

1. From terminal, use `git rm .sfdx` to delete the .sfdx directory on my online git (but not from my local repo).
2. With that gone, there shouldn't be a merge conflict, so I can complete the pull request of my branch back into the master.
3. Create a .gitignore file in my local repo that lists .sfdx, .vscode.

I'm unclear about your instruction to do the sfdx force:source:pull. Are you suggesting pulling source from my scratch org? I have all the latest code alive in VSCode (again, no other devs working on it, no other branches).

---

OK, making progress, and thanks @DavidReed for your comments. I had to add a bit to the git rm command: `git rm .sfdx -r --cached`. I didn't really have to cache it, but i figured it's tiny, so why not save it just in case I've done something wrong. But I did have to either use `--cached` or `-f` to force removal.

Next, in terminal, I used `touch .gitignore` to create the .gitignore file, then in VSCode editor, I added... `.sfdx 
.vim-force.com 
.vscode`
 
...and saved it.

I was able to merge my branch in with no conflicts. Hooray!

Now, I'm trying to understand where that .sfdx directory actually is. Just for verification (and the benefit of the next newbie who hits this thread)...

1. Online git repo -- it's grayed out here, I'm assuming because I cached it. If I had done `git rm .sfdx -r -f` it would be gone.
2. Local git repo -- don't see it here until I press Command-Shift-. to make Mac Finder show hidden files... and there it is, along with `.gitignore`.
3. VSCode (or presumably any other IDE) -- I see it here because it can see the .SFDX directory in my local repo, even if Mac Finder doesn't show it.

And now that I've included it in `.gitignore`, it will continue to be useful locally (for scratch org creation, etc.), but won't get pushed to my online git repo.

Thanks for all the help.